# umake android proxy error

Tags: networking, application-development, android, proxy, ubuntu-make

When I run in Ubuntu 16.10:

```
$ umake android --accept-license
ERROR: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html couldn't finish download: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='developer.android.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sdk/index.html (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',)))
ERROR: An error occurred while downloading https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='developer.android.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sdk/index.html (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',)))
```

It seems to be a proxy problem but I have no problems with apt.
How can I set the proxy values for umake?

My umake version is 16.05

Comment: so far as I know, that's a temporary error internal to `umake`.  Their server can only handle so many download requests concurrently.  (As I recall, could be wrong.)

Comment: Bug still occurring. I found no way to make this command work.